# Issue running Python turtle in Canopy

Tags: python, python-idle, turtle-graphics, canopy

I wrote this code:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
Matthew = turtle.Turtle() 
Matthew.forward(200)
Matthew.left(90)
Matthew.forward(200)
```

and saved it as Matthew.py
If I run Matthew.py using Idle I get the expected behaviour (new window opens and little turtle does its moves).
If I open and run Matthew.py in Canopy it just hangs there. All I see is:

```
%run /Users/matteoniccoli/Canopy/Notebooks/Matthew.py
```

but it just hangs there, no errors.

Am I doing something wrong?

Please notice as an experiment I copied the same code in a IPython notebook and saved it as Matthew.ipynb, then run the code in the notebook in Canopy and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Canopy Python uses a Qt GUI backend. Turtle uses a TK backend. They conflict. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/21793229-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel for resolution.